# List the Assets.xcassets contents

Tags: ios, swift5

I'm trying to list all files in the Assets.xcassets catalogue but I can't find a way to do it...
There are some images inside and I'm looking for a way to insert these filenames into an array.

If I try this code:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
```

I can list items outside the Assets.xcassets

I know that I can put the images outside but I'm wondering if there's a way to list the files inside the Assets.xcassets catalogue.

Is there a special path to that "folder" or a text list somewhere?

Comment: Using file manager document folder you can put into all images and access also till app install in your device. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager Please read it this document and let me know, what you want i will help you.

Comment: Using FileManager I'm not able to list the content of the Assets,xcassets catalog... I can't find a way... I'm wondering if there's a content list (JSON file to parse?) somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files from your `Assets.xcassets` are not simply copied into you app bundle.

Instead, Xcode compiles them into a special file called a `car` file - think of it as a sort of ZIP archive of all your assets.

The .car file format has been reverse engineered, e.g. at https://blog.timac.org/2018/1018-reverse-engineering-the-car-file-format/ but reading its content is quite a lot of hassle.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks a lot. A good reading to understand what's moving under the Xcode interface.